# When user changes the text size in their display settings, my flutter app text size is also changing and it is disturbing nearby widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

When user changes the text size in their display settings, my flutter app text size is also changing and it is disturbing nearby widgets, there by some part of the UI is becoming unusable. Is there any option to prevent changing of my flutter app text font sizes when system font size changes? If no option is available, how to overcome this problem? Surprisingly there is no much content about this issue on internet. Did anyone face such issues before?`No code is req.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `textScaleFactor` of your texts. Like:

```
Text(
  'hello',
  textScaleFactor: 1.0,
),
```

Or you can globally set it to 1.0 by:

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
   return MediaQuery(
   data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
   child: child,
  );
 },
 title: 'Home Page',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `textScaleFactor: 1` in `Text` Widget